# IF condition in C translation to MIPS

Tags: c, mips

I want to know why is the 
`if(x == y)` in C programming language translated into 
**'bne'** condition and not to **'beq'** condition in MIPS ?

Comment: bne => ne for `not equal`. beq => eq for `equal`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring the conditional for a moment, consider the order in which these blocks of code are likely to be printed in the assembler language instruction stream:

```
// A
if (x == y) {
    // B
}
// C
```

- When `x == y` is true, the flow goes sequentially from A to B to C. There's no jump required on equality (`beq`), because the desired flow matches the way the blocks are printed in the instruction stream.
- When `x == y` is false, at the end of A the flow has to bypass B and jump straight to C. That's why it makes sense that the branch instruction is triggered on inequality (`bne`).

---

Of course, take these only as an example thought process for this particular case.

In the general case, these are all implementation details. The compiler may print the instructions in any way it sees fit, including inverting conditionals. (Keep in mind that, due to modern CPU pipelines, it is usually a strong optimization goal for the compiler to successfully guess the most likely execution path and ensure that it contains the fewest possible jumps.)

Comment: why is it a goal to avoid from as much as possible jumps ? (of course besides the mess in the code)

Comment: @erezlale It's a strong optimization goal *for the compiler*, not the programmer (usually). You can read more about why, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining Keep in mind that this isn't necessarily applicable to your question. I just mentioned it in passing, to point out that high level conditionals might be inverted in the instruction stream by the compiler. That is, you shouldn't depend on the kind of branch instruction (`beq` or `bne` or anything else) when writing C code.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to branch over the if-block if the condition is false, than to execute the if-block if the condition is true.

Those sound very similar, but compare the following:

```
if (x == y)
{
    A;
}
B;
```

is equivalent to (pseudo-C `bne` variant):

```
if (x != y)
    goto not_equal;
A;
not_equal:
B;
```

which will branch only if `x != y`.

If you use `beq`, you get this mess:

```
if (x == y)
    goto equal;
goto not_equal;
equal:
    A;
not_equal:
B;
```

which will branch in both cases.

Even without an instruction pipeline, branching only sometimes is more efficient than always branching.